Fatal error in OpenCV function readNetFromONNX()
I have a working application that performs detection using ssd_mobilenet_v2, powered solely by OpenCV 4.6.0. My system is Ubuntu 24, C++17, CLion. I want to switch to v3, using ONNX format, but I experience fatal errors when trying to load the model:
Before load
[ERROR:0@0.104] global ./modules/dnn/src/onnx/onnx_importer.cpp (1018) handleNode DNN/ONNX: ERROR during processing node with 1 inputs and 1 outputs: [ReduceMax]:(onnx_node!/transform/ReduceMax) from domain='ai.onnx'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.6.0) ./modules/dnn/src/onnx/onnx_importer.cpp:1040: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'handleNode'
> Node [ReduceMax@ai.onnx]:(onnx_node!/transform/ReduceMax) parse error: OpenCV(4.6.0) ./modules/dnn/src/layers/reduce_layer.cpp:327: error: (-215:Assertion failed) inputs.size() > 0 in function 'getMemoryShapes'

Here is the function that produces this error:
void SSDModel::loadModelFromONNX()
{
    std::cout << "Before load" << std::endl;
    net = cv::dnn::readNetFromONNX(model_path);
    std::cout << "After load" << std::endl;
    net.setPreferableBackend(cv::dnn::DNN_BACKEND_DEFAULT);
    net.setPreferableTarget(cv::dnn::DNN_TARGET_CPU);
}

And full code for SSDModel class:
#include "SSDModel.h"
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

SSDModel::SSDModel(const std::string& model_path,
                   const std::string& class_file_path,
                   float conf_threshold,
                   float nms_threshold)
    : conf_threshold(conf_threshold),
      nms_threshold(nms_threshold),
      model_path(model_path),
      class_file_path(class_file_path)
{
    loadModelFromONNX();
    readClassFile();
}

SSDModel::~SSDModel() = default;

void SSDModel::detectObjects(const cv::Mat& image,
                             std::vector<int>& classIds,
                             std::vector<std::string>& classNames,
                             std::vector<float>& confidences,
                             std::vector<cv::Rect>& boxes)
{
    std::vector<int> indices = detect(image, classIds, confidences, boxes);

    std::vector<int> filteredClassIds;
    std::vector<std::string> filteredClassNames;
    std::vector<float> filteredConfidences;
    std::vector<cv::Rect> filteredBoxes;

    for (int index : indices) {
        filteredClassIds.push_back(classIds[index]);
        filteredClassNames.push_back(classes[classIds[index]]);
        filteredConfidences.push_back(confidences[index]);
        filteredBoxes.push_back(boxes[index]);
    }

    classIds = std::move(filteredClassIds);
    classNames = std::move(filteredClassNames);
    confidences = std::move(filteredConfidences);
    boxes = std::move(filteredBoxes);
}

int SSDModel::getClassNumber() const
{
    return classes.size();
}

std::vector<int> SSDModel::detect(const cv::Mat &image,
                                  std::vector<int> &classIds,
                                  std::vector<float> &confidences,
                                  std::vector<cv::Rect> &boxes)
{
    cv::Mat blob = cv::dnn::blobFromImage(image, 1.0, cv::Size(300, 300), cv::Scalar(), true, false);
    net.setInput(blob);

    cv::Mat output = net.forward();

    cv::Mat detections(output.size[2], output.size[3], CV_32F, output.ptr<float>());

    for (int i = 0; i < detections.rows; ++i)
    {
        float confidence = detections.at<float>(i, 2);

        if (confidence > conf_threshold)
        {
            int classId = static_cast<int>(detections.at<float>(i, 1)) - 1;
            int left = static_cast<int>(detections.at<float>(i, 3) * image.cols);
            int top = static_cast<int>(detections.at<float>(i, 4) * image.rows);
            int right = static_cast<int>(detections.at<float>(i, 5) * image.cols);
            int bottom = static_cast<int>(detections.at<float>(i, 6) * image.rows);

            classIds.push_back(classId);
            confidences.push_back(confidence);
            boxes.push_back(cv::Rect(left, top, right - left + 1, bottom - top + 1));
        }
    }

    std::vector<int> indices;
    cv::dnn::NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, conf_threshold, nms_threshold, indices);

    return indices;
}

void SSDModel::readClassFile()
{
    std::ifstream ifs(class_file_path);
    if (!ifs.is_open())
        CV_Error(cv::Error::StsError, "Class File not found: " + class_file_path);

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(ifs, line))
    {
        classes.push_back(line);
    }
}

void SSDModel::loadModelFromONNX()
{
    std::cout << "Before load" << std::endl;
    net = cv::dnn::readNetFromONNX(model_path);
    std::cout << "After load" << std::endl;
    net.setPreferableBackend(cv::dnn::DNN_BACKEND_DEFAULT);
    net.setPreferableTarget(cv::dnn::DNN_TARGET_CPU);
}

void SSDModel::loadModelFromTf()
{
    try {
        net = cv::dnn::readNetFromTensorflow("../resources/frozen_inference_graph.pb",
                                         "../resources/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29.pbtxt");
        setupNetwork();
    } catch (const cv::Exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error loading ONNX model: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        throw;
    }


}

void SSDModel::setupNetwork()
{
    net.setPreferableBackend(cv::dnn::DNN_BACKEND_DEFAULT);
    net.setPreferableTarget(cv::dnn::DNN_TARGET_CPU);

    std::vector<int> outLayers = net.getUnconnectedOutLayers();
    std::string outLayerType = net.getLayer(outLayers[0])->type;
    if (outLayerType != "DetectionOutput")
        CV_Error(cv::Error::StsNotImplemented, "Unexpected output layer type: " + outLayerType);
}

When using loadModelFromTf() instead of loadModelFromONNX(), everything works fine. I know that I have wrong blob size for v3, but that's not the point, since code never reaches this, it fails before. I've tried different ONNX files for ssd_v3, some produced same error, some - different, but every file resulted in error in this function.
Here is google drive folder with files that I've tried. The file that I've generated myself called ssdlite320_mobilenet_v3_large.onnx
EDIT: Updating to OpenCV 4.10 didn't help - error message changed, but still persists in the same function:
[ERROR:0@0.411] global onnx_importer.cpp:1036 handleNode DNN/ONNX: ERROR during processing node with 6 inputs and 1 outputs: [Concat]:(onnx_node!/transform/Concat_2) from domain='ai.onnx'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.10.0-dev) /home/kuver/Downloads/opencv-4.x/modules/dnn/src/onnx/onnx_importer.cpp:1058: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'handleNode'
> Node [Concat@ai.onnx]:(onnx_node!/transform/Concat_2) parse error: OpenCV(4.10.0-dev) /home/kuver/Downloads/opencv-4.x/modules/dnn/src/layers/concat_layer.cpp:104: error: (-215:Assertion failed) curShape.size() == outputs[0].size() in function 'getMemoryShapes'


upgrade opencv.

@ChristophRackwitz This didn't help. New error message: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  OpenCV(4.10.0-dev) /home/kuver/Downloads/opencv-4.x/modules/dnn/src/onnx/onnx_importer.cpp:1058: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'handleNode'

Node [Concat@ai.onnx]:(onnx_node!/transform/Concat_2) parse error: OpenCV(4.10.0-dev) /home/kuver/Downloads/opencv-4.x/modules/dnn/src/layers/concat_layer.cpp:104: error: (-215:Assertion failed) curShape.size() == outputs[0].size() in function 'getMemoryShapes'


ok great! I would guess that the model (in ONNX form) uses some ONNX features (layer types?) that really have not implemented yet in OpenCV. either there's an issue on opencv's github about it already, or you should file one. include everything required to repro the issue.
